# Is there a simple way to read scancodes from the keyboard without involving third-party libs?

Tags: keyboard, rust

I'm trying to build a shell project in Rust and I ran into trouble in the very beginning. Instead of reading the whole line and output through stdin/stdout, I want to parse every keypress and maintain a buffer until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. With an ability to move the cursor, backspace, access command history by up/down keys etc.

Comment: [The complete standard library API is documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/), so check that for relevant types and functions. You don't list any cross-platform requirements, so I'll assume you are on Linux. Perhaps you can just open `/dev/tty` or whatever? Most people would just use a crate to solve this problem (Rust **loves** crates), but asking for a library recommendation is *off topic* for Stack Overflow, so it's good that you didn't do that!

Comment: Ummm... why is it an offtopic? I hear it for the first time. Besides that I'm completely new to system programming, so I would appreciate any links to particular examples in Rust on how to open /dev/tty etc

Comment: @IvanYouroff: SO caters to questions that have an objective "best" answer. A Q&A is not a forum, so it is not suitable for debates and (in this case) pitching one library against another. SO also aims to have answers that last (ideally eternally valid), and best libraries tend to come and go, so that in 2 years the best library for a particular task may be completely different... and therefore the "recommendation" be completely off, which would mislead people.

Comment: I agree with the part about debates and holy wars, but most of the higher level programming problems are solved like "How do I do X?" - "Use library Y, here's the example" and even years later if library Z will be the better option, finding the answer mentioning Y would be a good starting point.